# can't see layout outline in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I open the layout file with Android Common XML Editor, in the graphic mode, it works fine,
but when switch it to source mode, the outline view become blank.

I'm using the ADT v22.0.5.

Does anyone knows what can be done in this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE you have used? And restart you